# Find a range in another Sheet

Tags: vba

I have the piece of code below:

```
       Selection.Find(What:="4", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
 Dim cl As Range, rTest As Range 

    Set rTest = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlToRight)) 
    For Each cl In rTest 
        If Not cl.Value > 0 Then 
            cl.EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
        End If 
    Next cl 
End Sub
```

Where says What=4, i would like to search the Range(e15) of another worksheet. Search the value of E15 in one sheet and look for it in a specific range in another sheet. I have all the other piece set, but I dont know how I can reference the value of e15, this can 4 or any other number. After finding, hide all columns that are not my specific value. Many thanks!

Comment: You should watch:[Excel VBA Introduction](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).  Here is the relevant video: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ)

Comment: `WsMain.Cells.Find("E15").Select` does not reference `Range("E15")` it searches the cells on ` WsMain` looking for the value `E15`.

Comment: search, yes. sorry wrong word there. thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should act like follows

```
Dim f As Range

Set f = Selection.Find(What:=Worksheets("otherWorksheetName").Range("e15").Value, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    f.Activate '<--| what do you need this for?

    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True '<--| hide all columns in wanted range
    f.EntireColumn.Hidden = True '<--| unhide found range column
End If
```

where you have to change "otherWorksheetName" to you actual "other " worksheet name

Comment: @ShaiRado, yes. I was correcting my code meanwhile. Thank you anyway

Comment: @LeandroMoreira, missed that part: what does _"After finding, hide all columns that are not my specific value"_ actually mean?

Comment: so, what I mean is. Lets say my range(e15) is 4. So when I find 4 in my specific range, all other numbers, 5, 8 whatever gets hidden.

Comment: No. all columns get hidden but the one with the found "4"